# python: How do I import PyAutoGUI

Tags: tkinter, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
```

I am getting an import error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
>      from pymsgbox import alert, confirm, prompt, password
> File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymsgbox/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
>       if tk.TkVersion < 8.0:
> AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TkVersion'

Comment: Did you name your script `tkinter.py`?

Comment: How is this error related to `PyAutoGui`?

Comment: acw1668 no i didnt

Comment: The Laggy Tablet -   i dont know, i think in some cases like opening window or something else PyAutoGui has some conflicts with tkinter  :|  now  however im using  pyscreenshot library  instead and its works

Answer (score 0):

The error *is* clearly showing `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'TkVersion'` so either your Tkinter module isn't updated, or your Tkinter module has some errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you didn't install pyautogui or don't you have the latest version (this can also be done by reinstalling it).
This video explains how to install pyautogui: https://youtu.be/-jxt7pVNAAk

The error looks unfamiliar to me, so I don't know if that's the issue. It also discribes more than 1 line.